# viewWillAppear vs. viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

What is the difference between `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

I know in `viewDidLoad` the sizes of view are not known. What about the other two methods? Which one better to use adjust position of subviews?

Comment: If you must adjust frames manually, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is where to do it.

Answer (score 6):

`viewWillAppear` is called only once each time the view is added to the view hierarchy. It occurs after `viewDidLoad`, but before animations are actioned on the view. See [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear) for more info.

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called every time the controller's view is updated, rotated, or changed (or more technically, each time its bounds change). See [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews) for more info.

Comment: I just noticed that sizes in `viewWillAppear` are not yet precise values.

Comment: Look at `viewDidAppear` which happens later. But even so sizes cannot be relied on until `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called on the controller or `viewDidLayout` on the view itself.